# Why is there no memory leak with non-virtual destructor

Tags: c++

I was told that there is no memory leak of `B->b` in the following code:

```
    struct A {}; // no virtual destructor
    struct B : public A {
    int b;
    }

    int main() {
        A* a = new B {};
        delete a;
    }
```

If it's true, could you explain why?

Comment: On most implementations, `delete` calls `free`, which does not take any size or type parameter, so the system somehow has other ways to know how much size was allocated at this address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that is how undefined behaviour works. Memory isn't guaranteed to leak. But neither is it guaranteed to not leak. Any behaviour is possible as far as the language is concerned.

> why this is Undefined Behaviour

Because a non-virtual destructor is called through a pointer whose dynamic type is of another (derived) type.

> whether anything concretely can be said about the lifetime of the B::b

Well, it is a member of `B`, so it has the same lifetime as any `B` object. As for the lifetime of the dynamic `B` object, we cannot really say much due to the UB.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why this is Undefined Behaviour, and whether anything concretely can be said about the lifetime of the `B::b` in OP's example?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete -- it's right before the "Notes" section. Alternatively, consult the according ISO standard.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your structure to leak.

Your destructor doesn't delete the object -- it deletes any memory the object itself creates. For instance, if your "int b" were instead something that itself required destruction, you might have a different problem.

But b itself doesn't require destruction.

You could test this after a fashion by doing almost the same, but making a second class that has a constructor and destructor. Add cout statements in each, and instead of "int b" have first a (non-pointer) instance to your new structure and then a pointer version (that you do a new Foo on), and see what happens.

Comment: No, the behavior is undefined, even if most compilers will work great here. You cannot assume an environment to supply the allocation size always with new-operator execution in order to be able to deallocate from base class/struct pointers.

Comment: PS: Relevant part from the standard ( http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#expr.delete-3 ): "In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type and <true>, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @Secundi I think we can agree that destructors should be virtual. It would be interesting to see what happens, however. If you run a loop a million times doing an alloc/free of this structure, does memory usage grow?

Comment: I think all modern compiler implementations will work great here, leaving no memory leaks (since simple underlying malloc/free-mechanisms are commonly used), as long as the derived class has no custom allocated heap members/dynamic resources. But as I said, in doubt, it's up to the implementation.

Comment: @Secundi It's not the job of the destructor to free the space used by the object. The destructor's job frees any additional memory allocated by the object. If the object only contains native fields (int, bool, etc) and destroying it doesn't require destroying sub-objects, doing it "wrong" is probably fine. But it's definitely an issue if your object has a std::string (for instance), as that won't get properly destroyed. Fairly certain that's the "undefined" part from the standard.

Comment: That's not the point here. The point is, that the standard doesn't define the characteristics of UB here in detail so only seen from the language point of view, you cannot assume how it should be realized actually even if it's clear for all known practical cases. One reason why the standard doesn't go into detail here might be the aspect, that you are allowed to overload new and delete operator. Think of a possible totally "weird" custom memory management, where it's required, that the deallocation of heap objects' space has access to the concrete type via RTTI to work appropriately.

Comment: It would somehow then be critical in terms of consistency to say, the default new/delete are potentially UB for this case and the custom ones are not (since they are quite fundamental operators/keywords, not just custom functions). I admit for this case, that might be only my personal opinion and I really appreciate any further information here.

Comment: and the points here I stated for the overload cases are actually applicable to a compiler implementation of the default ones too. If I understand the standard here correctly, no one forbids you to implement a (compiler-) deallocator implementation that requires virtual destructors for these cases to obtain the final deallocation information, even when the destructors themselves do not deallocate anything actually.